# Postgres 10 ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql

I'm using postgres10 on Windows.
In my query,that I copy the result to CSV, I want to have 1700 columns but I got this error:

> "ERROR:  target lists can have at most 1664 entries SQL state: 54000"

Any one have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: It would appear that you reached a limit of the product (it clearly says that you can have up to 1664 entries while you are attempting to have 1700). This does not appear to be an error.

Comment: So, there is no solution to push the limit right now?

Comment: Check postgresl's manual and see if there is an option that would change that limit (I mean, configuration). My wild guess would be that you can't. Incidentally, are you completely sure you need a table with 1700 columns (or even 1664)? If yes, I would strongly suggest you review your design.

Comment: You may be able to play with arrays or strings to get something pretty close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I search many documentation but I've got te same response: **it's the limit for postgres**. After dealing with the boss, I used concat_ws to concat columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit cannot be extended, and rightly so.

I recommend that you create a temporary table for these values and join with it. That has the additional advantage that you can `ANALYZE` the table for better estimates.

Comment: For sure, it's the limit.